# Abstract classes (with pure virtual methods) in Cython

Tags: c++, python, oop, cython

**Quick version:**
How to declare an abstract class in Cython? The goal is to declare interface only, so that other classes can inherit from it, there must be *no implementation* of this class.

interface.pxd:

```
cdef class IModel:
    cdef void do_smth(self)
```

impl.pyx:

```
from interface cimport IModel

cdef class A(IModel):
    cdef void do_smth(self):
        pass
```

Everything **nicely compiles**, but when I'm importing `impl.so` in python I get following:

```
ImportError: No module named interface
```

Apparently the method wasn't really virtual and python wants `IModel`'s instance

**More details:**

I have a cython extension class (`cdef class Integrator`) which should operate on any instance, implementing the `IModel` interface. The interface simply ensures that the instance have a method `void get_dx(double[:] x, double[:] dx)`, so that integrator can call it every integration step in order to, well, integrate the model. The idea is that one can implement different models in cython and then interactively integrate them and plot the reults in **python** scripts. Like that:

```
from integrator import Integrator # <-- pre-compiled .so extension
from models import Lorenz         # <-- also pre-compiled one, which inherits
                                  # from IModel

mod = Lorenz()
i = Inegrator(mod)
i.integrate()       # this one's really fast cuz no python is used inside

# do something with data from i
```

The `lorenz.pyx` class should look something like:

```
from imodel cimport IModel

cdef class Lorenz(IModel):
    cdef void get_dx(double[:] x, double[:] dx)
        # implementation
```

And the `integrator.pyx`:

```
from imodel cimport IModel

cdef class Integrator:
    cdef IModel model

    def __init__(self, IModel model):
        self.model = model

    # rest of the implementation
```

Ideally, IModel should *only* exist in the form of a class definition in a *cython header* file (i.e. imodel.pxd), but so far I could only achieve the desired functionality by writing an ugly dummy implementation class in `imodel.pyx`. The worst thing is that this useless dummy implementation has to be compiled and linked so that other cython classes can inherit from it.

**PS:** I think this is a perfect use case for abstract classes, however, if it in fact looks bad to you, dear OOP coders, please tell me which other approach shall I use.

Comment: Relevant discussion on the `cython-devel` mailing list: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2014-January/003899.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that it's not quite possible ([discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cython-users/-PrYBVm7lDE)). Currently, interfaces are not supported, apparently because they are not of a critical importance: usual inheritance works quite good.

Comment: Is this still applicable?

Answer (score -1):

How to declare an abstract class in C++
declare normal class but that class must have at least 1 pure virtual function.
    ex: class abc{
    virtual void show()=0        //pure virtual funcn.no defn at all 
    }

Comment: That's right. The problem is that it's not possible to do so in Cython