# Cython - How to call Child method not implemented by Parent when instantiating as type of Parent?

Tags: python, oop, cython

I am trying to abstract one class ([like shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976809/)).

But when trying to call a method implemented only in the child, I get an error (pretty much the same as in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850671/)).

Here is an example:

```
# compile with:
# python setup.py build_ext --inplace

cdef class MetaB:
    cdef meta_method(self):
        print("called c_meta_method")

cdef class B(MetaB):
    cdef method(self):
        print("Called method")

cdef class A:
    cdef:
        MetaB b

    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

    cdef c_call_b_method(self):
        self.b.method()
    
    def call_method(self):
        return self.c_call_b_method()

    cdef c_call_b_meta_method(self):
        self.b.meta_method()
    
    def call_meta_method(self):
        return self.c_call_b_meta_method()
```

When I try it, the parent class method works fine:

```
$ python -c "import A; A.A().call_meta_method()"
[out]: called c_meta_method
```

But the child method does not work:

```
$ python -c "import A; A.A().call_method()"
[out]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "A.pyx", line 24, in A.A.call_method
    return self.c_call_b_method()
  File "A.pyx", line 21, in A.A.c_call_b_method
    self.b.method()
AttributeError: 'A.B' object has no attribute 'method'
```

How can I abstract a class, but still allow the child to expose different methods?

Comment: Have you tried `(<B> self.b).method()`?

Comment: `MetaB` is pretty confusing here because it isn't a metaclass (and cdef classes don't support metaclasses)

Comment: @DavidW , could you elaborate on the "cdef classes don't support metaclasses" ?

Comment: @MechanicPig, type casting works as expected. Thanks for the suggestion, but if I knew the type "B" before hand, I would change it from "MetaB" to "B" instead in the class A definition. 
Would there be a way to typecast dynamically ? (this sounds strange for cython, though  >.<)

Comment: @zeh `cdef` defines C functions. Cython will not put them in the namespace of the class. Changing it to `def` should work.

Comment: Metas classes are detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python - note that a metaclass is not the same as a base class. cdef classes support inheritance (like you're doing) but not setting a metaclass. It's that simple. What you're doing is fine, I just think the name is misleading

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: B b instead of MetaB b

```
cdef class A:
    cdef:
        B b
```

We replaced `MetaB b` with `B b`. `MetaB` doesn't have the attribute `.method` which is why the error occurred.

### Solution 2: def instead of cdef

```
cdef class B(MetaB):
    def method(self):
        print("Called method")
```

Define `B.method` using `def` instead `cdef`. This will cause Cython to add `method` as an attribute to the `B` type

Comment: I understand why the error occurred, but the problem is that the type of b must be `MetaB`, as I would like to be able to add other implementations of MetaB.

Comment: Then MetaB needs to define the protocol (or static "duck" typing) for the child classes to implement.

Comment: @zeh I found another solution that allows you to keep `MetaB b`